# Guarding type when class property is symbol?

Tags: typescript

I was looking to use a symbol for a property, but I realize because I'm using `this[SYM]` syntax, I can't get guarding to work properly. I was wondering if there was a better syntax to get this to work.

```
const SYM = Symbol('SYM');
class Example {
  [SYM]?: string;
  get prop(): string {
    if (this[SYM]) return this[SYM];
    return 'default';
  }
}
```

However this works:

```
const SYM = Symbol('SYM');
class Example {
  [SYM]?: string;
  get prop(): string {
    const v = this[SYM];
    if (v) return v;
    return 'default';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narrowing the type of an *accessed property* does not narrow the type of the parent object. So checking `this[SYM]` doesn't tell TS anything, because it's not in a standalone variable. That's why extracting the value into `v` works - it's a standalone variable, so it can be narrowed.

A more concise version would be:

```
const SYM = Symbol('SYM');
class Example {
  [SYM]?: string;
  get prop() {
    return this[SYM] ?? 'default';
  }
}
```

No need to explicitly annotate the return value of `prop` once your typings are correct.